# What is the solution for $x+22=-6\sqrt{2x+9}$

Tags: radicals

So, I want to solve for x in the radical equation:

$x + 22 = -6\sqrt{2x+9}$

By Squaring each expression we get:

$(x + 22)^2 = (-6\sqrt{2x+9})^2$

$ x^2 + 44x + 484 = 36\cdot(2x+ 9) $

$ x^2 + 44x + 484 = 72x + 324 $

Now by solving the quadratic equation:

$ x^2  - 28x + 160 = 0 $

$x^2 - 20x - 8x + 160 = 0$

$x\cdot(x-20) -8\cdot(x-20) = 0 $

$ (x-20)\cdot(x-8) = 0 $

$ x = 20 $ or $ x = 8 $

But, none of the values of x satisfies the equation $x + 22 = -6\sqrt{2x+9}$, they satisfy the equation $x + 22 = 6\sqrt{2x+9}$. There should be an extraneous root that satisfies the equation $x + 22 = 6\sqrt{2x+9}$, but boot the roots satisfies this equation and none of them satisfies $x + 22 = -6\sqrt{2x+9}$.

Why is that so? And is there any complex/imaginary solution to the equation?

Comment: Just because some one asks you to solve something doesn't mean there actually *is* a solution.   And squaring both sides doesn't always add an extraneous solution.  Sometimes it doesn't add any (Ex.  $|x-3| = 4; (x-3)^2=16; x^2-6x-5=0;x=1,4$) and sometimes it adds *two* Ex. $|x-2| =-7$ then .... well, you can see.

Comment: $|x−3|=4; (x−3)^2 = 4^2; x^2-6x+9 = 16; x^2-6x-7 = 0; x^2+x-7x-7=0; x\cdot(x+1) -7\cdot(x+1)=0; (x+1)\cdot(x-7)=0;$ $x=-1$ or $x=7$, One root satisfies $x-3 = 4$ which is $7$ and the extraneous root $-1$ satisfies $x-3 = -4$. An extraneous root is added

Comment: $x=-1$ is not an extraneous root.   One solving $x-3 = 4$ and the other solving $x-3 =-4$ does not make either extraneous.

Comment: $x=-1$ does not satisfy the equation $x-3=4$, the definition of an extreneous root:
An "extraneous root" may be defined as "a value obtained. for an unknown in the solution of an equation which is not a. root of the equation."

Comment: But our original equation was *not* $x-3 =4$.  It was $|x-3| = 4$ by your very own definition $x=-1$ is *not* an extraneous root because $x=-1$ *is* a solution to $|x-3| = 4$.

Comment: If you want another example of an equation not adding any extraneous root consider $x+22 = 6\sqrt{2x+9}$ squaring both sides we get $x=20$ or $x=8$ and they both satisfy $x+22 = 6\sqrt{2x+9}$.  No extraneous roots!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it can be useful to find the domain of the equation before solving equations involving radicals.

By definition of the [*principal square root*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root), if $\sqrt {f(x)}=g(x)$, then $f(x)\geqslant0\wedge g(x)\geqslant 0$ holds, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are some algebraic expressions.

Thus, you have:

$$
\begin{align}&\begin{cases}\sqrt {2x+9}=\frac {x+22}{-6}\geqslant 0\\ 2x+9\geqslant0\end{cases}\\\\
\implies &\begin{cases}x\leqslant-22\\ x\geqslant-\frac 92\end{cases}\\\\
\implies &x\in\color{#c00}{\emptyset.}\end{align}
$$

Therefore, we don't need to solve the equation. Because, the domain of the equation is the empty set. This means, the real solution, indeed, doesn't exist.

---

In this part of the answer, we want to prove that the equation $x+22=-6\sqrt{2x+9}$ has no complex roots in general.

Let $\sqrt {2x+9}=z, z\in\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$. Then we have:

$$
\begin{align}x+22=\frac {z^2}{2}+\frac {35}{2}=\frac {z^2+35}{2}\end{align}
$$

This leads to:

$$
\begin{align}&\frac {z^2+35}{2}=-6z\\
\implies &z^2+12z+35=0\\
\implies &\Delta_z=36-35=1\geqslant 0.\end{align}
$$

This implies that $z\in\mathbb R$, which gives a contradiction. This completes the proof.

Comment: Ok. But is there any complex/imaginary solution

Comment: @Robario Well, I will expand my answer as soon as possible.

Comment: @Robario I expanded my answer. If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Just because we can *write* a question doesn't mean the question has any solutions.  For example I can with a perfectly straight face ask you to solve $|x-3|=-7$ (which is impossible as $|x-3| \ge 0 > -7$) and if you solve by squaring both sides to get $(x-3)^2 = (-7)^2$ and you do the work ($x^2-6x + 9 = 49; x^2-6x-40=(x-10)(x+4)=0$ so $x=10$ or $x=-4$) you get *only* extraneous solutions.

To show there is no solution we can look at the conditions.  For $\sqrt{2x+9}$ to exist we must have $2x +9 \ge $ or $x \ge -4\frac 12$.  But we must also have $\sqrt{2x+9}\ge 0$ and so $-6\sqrt{2x+9} \le 0$ and must have $x+22 < 0$ so $x < -22$.  A contradiction.

....

What about complex numbers....

The issue isn't about taking the square root of a negative number.  It's about defining *which* of the *two* square roots $2x+9$ we are going to consider to be *the* square root.  The only way for $x+22 = -6\sqrt{2x+9}$ is if we allow our selves have *either* square root be valid.

If we do that we get your extraneous roots.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that I do.  But that's okay.